# saving some money on cloud9 bill - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, multi-user, aws-cloud9

we have a 1 cloud9 per developer and want to reduce costs. Each machine/cloud9 have an elastic IP so they can connect to some databases as whitelisted IPs. Right now there is a VPC with a NAT with an IP but cloud9 does not let you start an environment in a private subnet, so no success in using the VPC's IP and save some bucks. How did you saved money with several cloud9 environments that needs an authorized IP?

Answer (score 1):

An Elastic IP address is only half a cent per hour, if not connected to a running Amazon EC2 instance. So, best you can save is 12c per day, which is unlikely to be significant.

More significant would be the use of Cloud9 auto-hibernation, where "Cloud9 can  automatically start and stop the EC2 instances to reduce your costs". This way, the instances will only be used during work hours.

See: [AWS Cloud9 FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/faqs/)